# Unify equal values ​in different column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, merge-conflict-resolution

Suppose I have a column like so:

```
COLUMN A     
abc           
dbe        
dbe        
abc        
abc        
ajk        
dbe        
abc
```

I expected the follow output:

```
KEY  
abc1   
dbe1
dbe2
abc2
abc3
ajk1
dbe3
abc4
```

The point is to give uniqueness to each duplicate.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't understand. What's your expected output?

Comment: A possible way is to use coalesce function from SQL, but I don't know how to perform this in Python

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. The expected output is the column KEY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['key'] = df.groupby('COLUMNA').cumcount().add(1)
df['key'] = df['COLUMNA'] + df['key'].astype(str)
print(df)

  COLUMNA   key
0     abc  abc1
1     dbe  dbe1
2     dbe  dbe2
3     abc  abc2
4     abc  abc3
5     ajk  ajk1
6     dbe  dbe3
7     abc  abc4
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem.